# Import of vertices attributes in igraph in R

Tags: r, attributes, igraph

I'm new to R, so sorry for such simple question, but I really don't know where is my problem...
I am trying to build a network:

```
library(igraph)
matrix_try <- read.csv2("~/Documents/RStudio/Cedges.csv", header = T , row.names = 1)
nodes <- read.csv2("~/Documents/RStudio/Cnode.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Files you can find [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BywPtaB8Msj2enZwMXZwWjdDUzQ&usp=sharing)

```
matrix_try <- as.matrix(matrix_try)
net <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix_try, nodes, mode = "undirected", weighted = T)
```

But there are no vertices attributes (type, protests):

```
 IGRAPH UNW- 28 48 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
     [1] BYT --Udar                                   BYT --Front.zmin                            
     [3] BYT --Svoboda      (...)
```

How to 'find' them??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would be great if the data could still be available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add node attributes using `?graph_from_adjacency_matrix`, they have not been added, hence not being able to find them.

Downloaded your files:

```
adj_mat <- read.csv("Cedges.csv", sep =";", row.names = 1)
nodes <- read.csv("Cnode.csv", sep =";") 
net <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(edges), mode = "undirected", weighted = T)
```

You can then use the built-in FUN `set_vertex_attr` like so

```
set_vertex_attr(net, "name", index = V(net), as.character(nodes$name))
set_vertex_attr(net, "protests", index = V(net), nodes$protests)
set_vertex_attr(net, "type", index = V(net), as.factor(nodes$type))
```

Use the attributes in plot

```
plot(net, vertex.color = V(net)$protests)
```

[image: net plot]